# Twig variable does not exist if the name contains underscores

Tags: php, twig

I can’t display a variable like `{{foo_bar}}`, but if I change the name to `fooBar` it works. How can I display variables that contain underscores?

Comment: Underscores are valid characters in Twig variables. There must be some other but elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Your variables are set as private. Your twig display is using your variable through the `getter` you set that probably doesn't have any underscore because the good practices are to be written in camelCase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's okay if you display variables that contain underscores. There is no error with it.

Comment: My variable is an attribute of object. i try to do this : {{object.foo_bar}} and it doesn't work. Is there any solutions?

Comment: provide more details to get an answer that solves your issue...

Comment: Ok simply i send an object in template like :

echo $twig->render('template',array('myObject',$myObject);

In my template i try to display an atribute like :

{{myObject.foo_bar}}

It doesn't work. But if i change the name of my attribute like fooBar it works well...